# Image picker iOS

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In my image picker I had used the following code

```
- (void)imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index completionHandler:(void(^)(UIImage *image))completionHandler
{
  NSDictionary *image = self.images[index];
  [self.library assetForURL:image[@"URL"] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    UIImage *returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullResolutionImage]
                                               scale:[representation scale]
                                         orientation:(int)[representation orientation]];
    completionHandler(returnImage);
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error loading asset");
}];
}
```

I select the image using the following code

```
[self.cameraRoll imageAtIndex:indexPath.row-1 completionHandler:^(UIImage *image) {
        myImage=image;
    }];
```

When I select first time it is giving the value as "nil" when I select the same image for second time, it is picking the image correctly.

How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will be helpful for someone, so posting the answer. We have to wait until the library is loaded, for that I am using the while loop... with this it is working perfectly

```
- (void)imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index completionHandler:(void(^)(UIImage *image1))completionHandler
{
__block BOOL isFinished = NO;

NSDictionary *image = self.images[index];


[self.library assetForURL:image[@"URL"] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {


    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    UIImage *returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullResolutionImage]
                                               scale:[representation scale]
                                         orientation:(int)[representation orientation]];

   isFinished = YES;

    completionHandler(returnImage);
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: Cannot load asset - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    isFinished = YES;
}];
while (!isFinished) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01f]];
}
}
```